# How to use multiple asyncio.DatagramProtocol() instances for a server?

Tags: python, udp, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a UDP server application that listens on three different sockets with asyncio.DatagramProtocol(). The `server_task` simply sends the data it has received back to the sender while `p1_task` and `p2_task` send packets to the clients and then get back the response.

However, when I run the code, none of the tasks seem to be receiving or processing any packets received from clients. This is my code below:

```
import asyncio
import os
from collections import OrderedDict
from contextlib import AsyncExitStack
from datetime import datetime
import time

class ServerProtocol(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, clients):
        self.clients = clients

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        message = data.decode()
        receive_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        client_addr = addr[0]
        response = f"Received {message} at {receive_time}".encode()
        self.transport.sendto(response, addr)
        if client_addr not in self.clients:
            self.clients[client_addr] = [(None, None), (None, None)]


class P1Protocol(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, clients, srcAddr):
        self.clients = clients
        self.srcAddr = srcAddr

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        message = data.decode()
       

    def send_packet(self, addr):
        msg = ""
        self.transport.sendto(msg.encode(), (addr, 11111))


class P2Protocol(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, clients, srcAddr):
        self.clients = clients
        self.srcAddr = srcAddr

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        message = data.decode()
        

    def send_packet(self, addr):
        msg = ""
        self.transport.sendto(msg.encode(), (addr, 11111))


async def main() -> None:
    
    clients = {}
    p1_proto = P1Protocol(clients, "55::4")
    p2_proto = P2Protocol(clients, "55::5")
    server_task = asyncio.ensure_future(loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
                protocol_factory=lambda: ServerProtocol(clients),
                local_addr=("55::1", 12345),
                family=socket.AF_INET6,))

    p1_task = asyncio.ensure_future(loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
            protocol_factory=lambda: p1_proto,
            local_addr=("55::4", 12346),
            family=socket.AF_INET6,
            ))

    p2_task = asyncio.ensure_future(loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
            protocol_factory=lambda: p2_proto,
            local_addr=("55::5", 12347),
            family=socket.AF_INET6,
            ))

    await asyncio.gather(server_task, p1_task, p2_task)
    
    while True:
        timer = time.monotonic()
        if time.monotonic() - timer >= 1.0:
            if len(clients) > 0:
                for client in clients.keys():
                    p1_proto.send_packet(client)
                    p2_proto.send_packet(client)
            # Do stuff here
        # Do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I was expecting the program to continue running until it is interrupted and processing packets received from clients.